# How to rewrite timthumb image on nginx?

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have original image as below:

```
site.com/content/year/month/imagename.jpg
```

I use timthumb to generate thumbnail, so new link as below:

```
site.com/content/timthumb.php?src=site.com/content/year/month/imagename.jpg&w=A&h=B&zc=1
```

I want rewrite timthumb image url to:

```
site.com/img/year/month/imagename.jpg
```

Please help me and thank you very much!

-- I have try many way, but not work. Below is some:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/img/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif) /content/timthumb.php?src=site.com/content/$1/$2/$3.$4&h=150&w=150&zc=1 break;
}

location / {
rewrite ^/img/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif) /content/timthumb.php?src=site.com/content/$1/$2/$3.$4&h=150&w=150&zc=1 last;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's fair to get us to do all the work for you. Have you not tried anything? Any research?

Comment: I have edited topic, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have nginx, but, after some research, this could work for you:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^img/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif) content/timthumb.php?src=site.com/content/$1/$2/$3.$4&h=150&w=150&zc=1 last;
}
```

I've only removed the leading slashes (which one normally does in Apache too).

**Update:** Used [this generator](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) to come up with this. Please give it a try.

```
location /img {
    rewrite ^/img/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif) /content/timthumb.php?src=site.com/content/$1/$2/$3.$4&h=150&w=150&zc=1 break;
}
```

Comment: Last try: I have updated my answer with an escaped dot `\.`. If that doesn't work, then I'm sure someone else will be able to figure it out.

Comment: This could be a TimThumb issue - perhaps try swapping out `src=site.com` for `src=http://example.com` (and change `example` to `site` as StackOverflow will not allow me to use that URL). It would also help if you explain what the problem is. Are you getting an error? If so, what error?

Comment: Have updated my answer. The generator used adds the slashes in, and uses `break` instead of `last`.